# Trouble fetching JSON from an Express API with React

Tags: reactjs, express

I want to create an express API for my website that will return JSON. In order to achieve this I have changed the code in the default `users.js` route.
Here's the code of `routes/users.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/categories', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json([
    {user_id: 1, name: "Jack"},
    {user_id: 2, name: "John"}
  ]);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I fetch and print this JSON in my `App.js` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TopBar from './Components/TopBar';
import Timeline from './Components/Timeline';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
    }; 
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/users')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(users => this.setState({users}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <TopBar/>
        <Timeline/>
        {this.state.users.map(user => 
          <li key={user.user_id}>{user.name}</li>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  };
}

export default App;
```

It works fine without any errors, however I also wanted to fetch a list of categories, so I created a `routes/categories.js` file with the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET categories listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json([
    {category_id: 1, name: "Math"},
    {category_id: 2, name: "English"},
    {category_id: 3, name: "Business"},
    {category_id: 4, name: "Politics"}
  ]);
});

module.exports = router;
```

The problem is that when I try to fetch JSON from this route in my `Categories.js` component, it doesn't work. Here's the component's code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Categories extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          categories: [],
        }; 
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/categories/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(categories => this.setState({categories}));
        console.log(this.state.categories);
      }
      render() {
          return (
              <>
                {this.state.categories.map(category => 
                    <li key={category.category_id}>{category.name}</li>
                )}
              </>
          )
      }
}

export default Categories;
```

I receive the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I don't know if it's a syntax error or I'm not using the correct design pattern in Express. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Should it be `router.get('/categories`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one problem that immediately jumps out is that if you are fetching from a backend you need to include the entire url in your fetch requests on the front end e.g. http://localhost:8000/users

Comment: I have added a proxy in my package,json so all the requests will be sent to that url. I only have to specify the endpoint.

Comment: I see, maybe the problems lies in your main server.js file for you backend. Maybe some configuration step that wasn't added? Like adding the router variables to app.use() with the appropriate extensions such as "/categories" and "/users".

Comment: Yes, that seemed to be the problem alongside with CORS. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so just like Noah Kanyo said, the problem was because I didn't specify the routes in the main `app.js` file of express. I added the following code to the file and it worked:

```
var categoriesRouter = require('./routes/categories');
app.use('/categories',categoriesRouter);
```